# Secret security in containerised environment

Tags: sensitive-data-exposure, azure, secrets-management, environment-variables

I've been having a discussion with a developer about storing sensitive information in environment variables. Specifically within a containerised environment such as Azures Container apps.

> Background information
> In container apps you are able to pass
> secrets during the container build process from the azure environment.
> These are then exposed as system wide env variables within the
> container.

My thought process here is that although the container configuration very much limits the risk it doesn't remove it completely. While there are very few running processes that would also be able to access the env variables, one of those processes is internet facing. Also anyone that can access the container environment in azure can access these secrets.

My preferred method is to obtain the secrets as needed from the Azure key vault, but this poses some technical code challenges.

Lots of frameworks, blogs and guides suggest that accessing this information from environment variables is fine. However I also get the sense that was because vaults are relatively new and it was just the best choice before.

Question:

Is storing secrets in environment variables secure as using a key vault?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'm guessing it's not... What about HSMs, is that an option for you?..

Comment: @SirMuffington Unfortunately not, maybe in some distant future version but certainly not where we currently are

Answer (score 0):

*Is storing secrets in environment variables secure as using a key vault?*
The short answer is **No**.
A variable will never be *as secure* as a vault.
It is always recommended to use a key vault whenever possible.
You want to isolate/separate the secrets from developers and applications.
Further info, I recommend this post: [Azure Key Vault vs Azure Environment Variables - Which is the right way?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120045/azure-key-vault-vs-azure-environment-variables-which-is-the-right-way)

See more here that might help with the coding:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671135/how-to-pass-the-secret-from-azure-key-vault-to-environmental-variable
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli

In general, using a key vault makes your development work more portable.

Just add the line to your Function App:
`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)`
See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables#secure-values
Remember to rotate more often when not using a key vault